# Centroid of a Cluster - KMedoids

Tags: java, machine-learning, k-means

I am using the following Java-ml library, specifically, I am using the KMedoids ([http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/...](http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/api/0.1.0/net/sf/javaml/clustering/KMedoids.html)) class to cluster objects.

I am able to cluster the data, but I want to extract the centroid object in each cluster, how do I do this?

Comment: Compute the mean of each cluster and the look for the nearest point to that mean.

Comment: The whole point of KMedoids is that the centroid *is* an object. Having to go through all of the objects to find the centroid and find the closest is therefore poor, but if its the only option I guess thats what I will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that you need to find the median in any cluster. You can find the median by sorting and then taking the midpoint, requiring O(n lg n) time. If you need to find the median with each object insertion, then you need to do [online median selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387497/find-median-value-from-a-growing-set): keep two heaps, maxheap for all objects less than the median, and a minheap for all objects greater than the median. Object insertion will be O(lg n) time.