# Given that integers are read from a data stream. Find median of elements read so for in efficient way

Tags: java, c, algorithm, data-structures, median

Can we use AVL tree for this, so that root element is the median at any point

Comment: If you read them from a stream will this increase performance?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387497/find-median-value-from-a-growing-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AVL-trees are height-balanced, you need a weight-balanced tree.

Comment: u can have mixture of BST and AVL
step 1-insert a number based on value (right or left)
step 2-balance tree

Comment: well but what you actually mean is balancing based on the number of nodes in the subtrees. The AVL-criterion is balancing based on the height of the subtrees, which is not what you want for getting the median value.