# Calculating the median at each pixel for multiple frames OpenCV (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv

The task is to extract stable background out of the video, the idea is to choose n random frames from the video and take median for each pixel. I was doing this task in python using numpy

`medianFrame = np.median(frames, axis=0).astype(dtype=np.uint8)`

But now i need to perform the same task in **C++**. I have tried the naive way of splitting channels and going through rows*cols number of pixels for n frames to calculate the median frame but its not efficient at all and takes way more time than what np.median was taking. I also try to use xtensor for performing the task but wasn`t able to worlk with it. Any suggestions or direction about how to approach this task would greatly help me, Thanks!

Comment: I think for the task above, your way is correct and it is true that it will take more time than python. Basically numpy library is built on C++ but it deals with bits of the data and thus is fast.

Comment: So you wanna calculate median for each pixel coordinate in n different frames? If so, you can calculate it by reaching each frame's pixel by one by

Comment: Have you tried using matrix addition?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk thats exactly what i am doing right now and its extremely expensive computationally

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38916002/5008845)

Comment: @RahulKedia No, i have not matrix addition, how can i exploit that for calculating median?

Comment: I'd try 'cv::Mat::forEach' combined with 'std::nth_element'. ForEach is multithreaded in the background so I'd expect faster calculation. I assume that accessing (read-only) the corresponding elements in sequence of images will be safe in this context (it has to be done in foreach body so it can be invoked on other thread).

Comment: What is the number of frames you are talking about ?

Comment: Are you using pointer arithmetic for image traversal?

Comment: @Zdar there will be 25 at least FHD frames.

Comment: @eldesgraciado yeah but now i am trying to work with cv::Mat::forEach, suggested by michelson which is much faster

Comment: any of you that suggested `std::nth_element`, perhaps turn that into an answer